# Connect Microsoft Teams to GitHub

Tags: github, microsoft-teams

I have been trying to connect MS teams to GitHub, so anytime there is a pull request or push made, it will send an update to MS teams group channel.

I followed the instructions here to create a webhook. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/connectors/connectors-using(Setting up a custom incoming webhook)

I was able to post a message to the webhook using powershell. I was able to verify it on the microsoft teams channel associated with the webhook url but when I try to manage the webhook using GitHub by using the PayLoad URL. I'm getting 400 response code. 
Bad payload received by generic incoming webhook.

Help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Could you please try to configure [Github connector](http://www.sangadjiprabowo.com/post/2017/01/19/integrating-github-and-vsts-repository-with-microsoft-teams-using-office-365-connectors) in Teams channel?

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways you can achieve this easily. Because you are using Microsoft Teams I believe it is easy to signup to Azure Devops board. And then make a connector to Github.

Please follow the below link

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/github/connect-to-github?view=azure-devops

Once it is successfully authenticated.

1. In the desired channel > click three dots >  Select Connectors > find the `Azure Devops connector like below

[image]

2. Then you will be given with various options to send notifications to MSFT teams.

Using this in my work place. Works fab.

Second way:

1. Instead of Azure devops from the first screen shoot > choose github.
2. Then you will be given with options to send notifications

Hope it helps.